# PyTorch: torch.mode excluding a certain value

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

I am wondering how can I get the mode of a tensor along a certain axis excluding however a certain value.

For example, the mode of `a` excluding the value `0`:

```
a = [[1,2,2], [1,0,0], [1,3,1]] -> [2, 1, 1]
```

I am also not sure what the numpy approach would be.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `apply_along_axis`. In torch, it will look like this:

```
import torch


def _filter(arr, filter_vals):
    return arr[~torch.isin(arr, filter_vals)]


def mode_and_filter(arr, filter_vals, axis):
    return apply_along_axis(lambda a: torch.mode(_filter(a, filter_vals))[0], axis, arr)

...

print(mode_and_filter(arr, torch.Tensor([0]), axis=0))
```

In NumPy, there is function [.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), and it can be implemented similarly.